# Transform a point from map A to map B

Tags: opencv, math, geometry

I´m trying to transform a point from one map to another. I´ve tried to use some OpenCV sample code for getAffineTransform(), getPerspectiveTransform(), warpAffine() and findHomography(), but there´re always some kind of gaps in my transformation mesh. The feature points are usually detected on very different positions, so I need a good interpolation method, I think.

About the maps:
Both maps are images which are containing human body parts and human skin. I´m using the OpenCV feature detection/matching algorithmns to get a couple of equal points in both maps. The tricky thing is they´re containing arms and feets, too. Feature points on arms/feets can have much bigger offsets than the points on the torso.

The goal:
I want to transform any point on map A as good as possible to the equivalent position on map B.

My current approach is to find the three most clostest points to my original point on map A and construct a triangle. Afterwards I transform this triangle to the same three feature points on map B. That´s working nice if I have a lot of close feature point surrounding my original point. But on larger areas without feature points I got some problems with the interpolation.

Is this a good way to do so? Or is there a much better solution?
My favorite one would be the contruction of a complete transformation map for both images, but I´m not sure how to do this. Is it possible at all?

Thanks a lot for any advice!

**Simple sketch of the transformation** (I´m trying to find the points X1 to X3 from the left image in the right image):
[Sketch of a sample transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eUr9.jpg)

**Sample for homography (OpenCVSharp):**

```
Mat imgA = new Mat(@"d:\Mesh\Left2.jpg", ImreadModes.Color);
Mat imgB = new Mat(@"d:\Mesh\Right2.jpg", ImreadModes.Color);

Cv2.Resize(imgA, imgA, new Size(512, 341));
Cv2.Resize(imgB, imgB, new Size(512, 341));

SURF detector = SURF.Create(500.0);
KeyPoint[] keypointsA = detector.Detect(imgA);
KeyPoint[] keypointsB = detector.Detect(imgB);

SIFT extractor = SIFT.Create();
Mat descriptorsA = new Mat();
Mat descriptorsB = new Mat();
extractor.Compute(imgA, ref keypointsA, descriptorsA);
extractor.Compute(imgB, ref keypointsB, descriptorsB);

BFMatcher matcher = new BFMatcher(NormTypes.L2, true);
DMatch[] matches = matcher.Match(descriptorsA, descriptorsB);

double minDistance = 10000.0;
double maxDistance = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Length; ++i)
{
    double distance = matches[i].Distance;
    if (distance < minDistance)
    {
        minDistance = distance;
    }
    if (distance > maxDistance)
    {
        maxDistance = distance;
    }
}

List<DMatch> goodMatches = new List<DMatch>();
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Length; ++i)
{
    if (matches[i].Distance <= 3.0 * minDistance &&
        Math.Abs(keypointsA[matches[i].QueryIdx].Pt.Y - keypointsB[matches[i].TrainIdx].Pt.Y) < 30)
    {
        goodMatches.Add(matches[i]);
    }
}

Mat output = new Mat();
Cv2.DrawMatches(imgA, keypointsA, imgB, keypointsB, goodMatches.ToArray(), output);

List<Point2f> goodA = new List<Point2f>();
List<Point2f> goodB = new List<Point2f>();
for (int i = 0; i < goodMatches.Count; i++)
{
    goodA.Add(keypointsA[goodMatches[i].QueryIdx].Pt);
    goodB.Add(keypointsB[goodMatches[i].TrainIdx].Pt);
}

InputArray goodInputA = InputArray.Create<Point2f>(goodA);
InputArray goodInputB = InputArray.Create<Point2f>(goodB);

Mat h = Cv2.FindHomography(goodInputA, goodInputB);

Point2f centerA = new Point2f(imgA.Cols / 2.0f, imgA.Rows / 2.0f);
output.DrawMarker((int)centerA.X, (int)centerA.Y, Scalar.Red, MarkerStyle.Cross, 50, LineTypes.Link8, 5);

Point2f[] transformedPoints = Cv2.PerspectiveTransform(new Point2f[] { centerA }, h);
output.DrawMarker((int)transformedPoints[0].X + imgA.Cols, (int)transformedPoints[0].Y, Scalar.Red, MarkerStyle.Cross, 50, LineTypes.Link8, 5);
```

Code snippet for perspective transform (different approach, OpenCVSharp):

```
pointsA[0] = new Point(trisA[i].Item0, trisA[i].Item1);
pointsA[1] = new Point(trisA[i].Item2, trisA[i].Item3);
pointsA[2] = new Point(trisA[i].Item4, trisA[i].Item5);

pointsB[0] = new Point(trisB[i].Item0, trisB[i].Item1);
pointsB[1] = new Point(trisB[i].Item2, trisB[i].Item3);
pointsB[2] = new Point(trisB[i].Item4, trisB[i].Item5);

Mat transformation = Cv2.GetAffineTransform(pointsA, pointsB);

InputArray inputSource = InputArray.Create<Point2f>(new Point2f[] { new Point2f(10f, 50f) });
Mat outputMat = new Mat();
Cv2.PerspectiveTransform(inputSource, outputMat, transformation);
Mat.Indexer<Point2f> indexer = outputMat.GetGenericIndexer<Point2f>();
var target = indexer[0, 0];
```

Comment: Do you have any code example?

Comment: Thanks. Added some sample code for homography.

Comment: What kind of transformation are you looking for? You are using a perspective transform here, but is this reasonable? It sounds like you might need a general non-linear transform. Maybe, a vector field from optical flow?

Comment: I´ve added a sample sketch of the transformation. I hope it will explain it better than my description text. Thanks Nico, I will study your note about the optical flow in OpenCV.